# Type of mineral oil ot remove snake mites?

Tags: snakes

I see people mention that they use mineral oil to kill and remove mites from the snake but I'm not sure what kind of mineral oil to use. When I looked up mineral oil I seen there's different kinds. Can someone please tell me what kind to use?

Comment: See also: [My pet snake seems to have some sort of bugs crawling on its face; do I need to worry?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/197/my-pet-snake-seems-to-have-some-sort-of-bugs-crawling-on-its-face-do-i-need-to)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any mineral oil to use for mites on snakes, but my medicine reference books say that soaking in multiple plain lukewarm water also gets rid of them. This will also help to remove excess skin that might also contribute to the problem.